# R Library issues - cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’

Tags: r

When I try to run a particular function: I get the following error:

```
> wrangled_devices <- wrangle_devices(params$filtered_devices)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
```

So I figure I'll update the package as instructed. But that doesn't work:

```
install.packages("rlang")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/thebi/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1721024 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\thebi\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\thebi\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘rlang’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\thebi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO2wx0n\downloaded_packages
```

If I try to manually delete the rlang folder, it won't let me saying it's in use in another program, ever though I've closed R studio. I could force the point, but I' afraid of breaking something.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure what's going on here. I suspect once I sort this library, there will be 100 others that need the same treatment.

Comment: Turns out if you have an R or Rmd file open in vscode, while having some R plugins installed, this is what happens... Don't know whether to delete this question or post an answer sharing this discovery.

Comment: Clear your workspace. Close all instances. Start new and install rlang.

Comment: @TarJae Hey. No the issue is that aside from Rstudio, which is where I work, an R file was open in vscode as part of another project. Somehow vscode recognised this was an r file and was preventing me from working with the packages in RStudio. It's fixed now.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should post it as an answer. Because for me this is new.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this behaviour was as follows. The main R project was open in RStudio. It was inside this environment that I was experiencing the problems.

However, since my R code is actually built into a docker image, as part of a larger CI/CD controlled project, I happened to have a couple of R and Rmd files open in vscode. My vscode has several R plugins installed (it actaully promopts you to do this when it recognises an R file).

And as it turns out, vscode prevents you from working with your packages in RStudio. The message about the folder or file being open in another program must stem from vscode opening them in the background.

Comment: I also needed to remove the old rlang package before I could install the new one. Maybe this is helpful to someone.

Comment: I closed vs code and restarted R Studio to update the packages, then everything is fine.